# Move Boot To ZFS From SSD and Use SSD as ZFS Cache

Tags: boot, ssd, cache, zfs

I've got an SSD I want to use as cache for ZFS but it's the boot drive at present.  The ZFS is set up to mirror two 3TB hard drives and the remaining SATA port (of the 4 on the motherboard) is for the DVD.

So, I need to boot off the ZFS pool instead of the SSD and then install the SSD as cache or the ZFS pool somehow.

I don't suppose there are tools with few enough moving parts to make such a transition relatively risk free are there?